# JAVA Persistance OrderBy before a GroupBy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpql

we need to get the last post message group by a transmitter.

`Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Message m " +
                    "JOIN m.transmitter " +
                    "JOIN m.recipient " +
                    "WHERE m.transmitter = :u1 " +
                    "OR m.recipient = :u1 " +
                    "GROUP BY m.recipient,m.transmitter " +
                    "ORDER BY m.sendDate DESC");
            query.setParameter("u1", actualUser);`

but we need something like this where we get the oldest message:

`Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Message m " +
                    "JOIN m.transmitter " +
                    "JOIN m.recipient " +
                    "WHERE m.transmitter = :u1 " +
                    "OR m.recipient = :u1 " +
                    "ORDER BY m.sendDate DESC"
                    "GROUP BY m.recipient,m.transmitter ");
            query.setParameter("u1", actualUser);`

Thanks for help sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to get all contact first and then get the last send message from a contact (two queries instead of one big.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Message m " +
                "WHERE m.sendDate = (" +
                "SELECT MAX(m.sendDate) FROM MESSAGE m "
                "JOIN m.transmitter t " +
                "JOIN m.recipient r " +
                "WHERE t = :u1 " +
                "OR r = :u1)");
        query.setParameter("u1", actualUser);
```